# Como fazer divs com mesma altura e 100% de altura

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso que 3 divs que tenho tenham a mesma altura, e caso a altura não seja 100%, vire 100%.
Exemplo: Tenho 3 divs

```
<div class="menuEsquerdo"></div>

<div class="toggle"></div>

<div class="conteúdo"></div>
```

Quando toggle é clicado o menu é diminuído.O menuEsquerdo precisa ser fixo(deve permanecer) quando é preciso deslizar com o mouse para baixo(caso haja muito texto no assunto) , e caso se precise deslizar para o lado direito o menu também deve ser fixo porém o mesmo deve "levar" junto o toggle e "levar" o fundo do menu(caso o menu não esteja preenchido 100%).

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

**Normal**

[image: Caso Normal]

**Deslizando para baixo**

[image: Deslizando para Baixo]

**Deslizando para o lado**

[image: Deslizando para o lado]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode reproduzir essa funcionalidade com um pouco de CSS e JavaScript.

Primeiro o HTML:

```
<!-- O nome das classes já explica o que cada elemento representa -->
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="toggle"></div>
<div class="conteudo"></div>
```

Código CSS:

```
body{
    padding-left:230px;
}
body.expandido{
    padding-left:30px;
}
.menu, .toggle{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.menu{
    width:200px;
    background:#555;
}
.toggle{
    width:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    left:200px;
}
.conteudo{
    padding:10px;
}
.sumido{
    margin-left:-200px;
}
```

E por último um pouco de JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('.toggle').on('click',function(){
    var toggle_menu = $('.toggle, .menu'),
        body = $('body');

    if(!$(this).hasClass('sumido')){
        toggle_menu.addClass('sumido');
        body.addClass('expandido');
    }else{
        toggle_menu.removeClass('sumido');
        body.removeClass('expandido');
    }
});
```

#### Como funciona?

O que nós fizemos acima foi fixar o elemento `.menu` e o elemento `.toggle` no layout da página, de forma que nem com scroll eles sumam. Alem disso, atribuímos um `padding` ao elemento `body` para ele empurrar todo o seu conteúdo para direita, de forma que esse conteúdo não seja sobreposto pelo menu.

E o código JavaScript nada mais faz do que trocar classes CSS para alterar a posição destes elementos.

#### [`Exemplo`](http://jsfiddle.net/HpxnT/)

Comment: ficou muito bom, estava testando aqui, porém como eu poderia colocar um header e um footer na página já que a página ficaria quebrada?

Answer (score 1):

Pela descrição e pelas imagens me parece que você pretende criar um *dashboard*.

Não que não seja possível de ser feito do zero, mas não há necessidade de se reinventar a roda quando existem soluções prontas e compatíveis com os mais diversos browsers como o Bootstrap.

Das tantas possibilidades existentes, uma bem próxima seria [esta](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo ponto negativo, seja você quem for.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar a altura do navegador via jQuery ou JavaScript e declarar um CSS pra essas `divs` com essa altura. Exemplo com jQuery:

```
var altura = $(window).height();
$('.alvo').css('height', altura);
```

Answer (score -3):

Ola uma boa ideia de concertar o codigo é só
fixe o elemento .menu e o elemento .toggle no layout da página. Depois  atribuia um padding ao elemento body para ele empurrar todo o seu conteúdo para direita, de forma que o que esteja dentro não seja sobreposto pelo menu.