# CSS layout responsivo em colunas

Tags: html, css, css3, layout-responsivo

Estou fazendo um layout que possuirá duas colunas, a primeira na esquerda irá compor um menu a segundo irá ocupar todo o espaço restante na tela do lado direito e nela ira ficar o conteúdo.

Ao desenvolver o css dessas colunas me deparei com o seguinte problema a primeira coluna(.sidebar) é float left a segunda(.maincontent) não, pois o width terá que ser responsivo entretanto ao colocar conteudo dentro da `.maincontent` a quebra de linha dos conteúdos é correspondente ao tamanho da `.sidebar` por esse motivo a orientação do conteúdo na `.maincontent` ficava errada, a quebra de linha ficava muito grande e desproporcional, pra tentar resolver este problema defini a `.maincontent` como float left e pronto o problema aparentemente foi resolvido mas de repente surgiu outro, o width da .maincontent ficou proporcional ao conteudo ao envés de ocupar o espaço restante da tela, e eu não estou conseguindo resolver este problema deixar a quebra de linha da .maincontent certa e independente e o width responsivo.

para melhor entendimento vou anexar os **Screenshots** e os exemplos no **jsfiddle.net**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [Link do exemplo editável jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8K2Z/1/)
>
> [Link do exemplo fora do iframe](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a8K2Z/1/show/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [Link do exemplo editável jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWbCD/2/)
>
> [Link do exemplo fora do iframe](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rWbCD/2/show/)

**Gostaria de uma solução sem ter que usar width em porcentagem como nesta [dashboard](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0977873).**

Comment: Cara, já tentou usar o bootstrap ? Com ele é muito fácil do que você fazer diretamente na mão... Nele já vem tudo de forma fácil de se usar.

Comment: Cara talvez eu não tenha procurado direito rsrs mas pesquisei e não encontrei essa solução no bootstrap, se você tiver algum exemplo será bem vindo.

Comment: Eu acho, que essa parte do tutorial será muito bem vinda pra você: [nesse link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Como ele trabalha com grid, dá pra você fazer exatamente o que quer ! Isso que está nas imagens né. Aqui no [DevMedia tem outro tutorial de como usar o bootstrap](http://www.devmedia.com.br/twitter-bootstrap-aumentando-sua-produtividade/24967)

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta totalmente coerente com seu contexto e uma duvida aceitável e totalmente bem explicada eu não entendo porque os downvote e ainda por cima ninguém deixa comentário isso pra mim é falta de caráter!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recentemente eu respondi [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16660/1754) onde a solução, em grande parte, pode ser aplicada aqui também.

Você pode resolver este problema da seguinte forma:

```
.menu{ /* estilo atribuído ao elemento que contém o menu */
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:200px;    
}
body{
    padding-left:200px /*padding do tamanho do width do menu*/
}
```

Segue um [**`exemplo prático`**](http://jsfiddle.net/TZB7H/).

Comment: Lembrei daquela mesma pergunta ao ler essa questão!

Comment: @Kazzkiq muito obrigado parece que só você realmente leu minha pergunta e entendeu! sua solução funciona muito bem pra mim!